# A web partial update effect in Facebook with URL changed

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, page-refresh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

I found that in Facebook if I click the *Notes* or *Music* links on left section, only the central section gets refreshed while the URL is changed, from www.facebook.com to www.facebook.com/*Notes*.

As I know, changing URL will trigger whole page reload. What magic does Facebook do to its web pages?

Comment: have a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Comment: It's called `pushState`. Take a look at [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/). Note, not all browsers and versions support this functionality, so you should consider a library instead of rolling your own, or investigating how the plugins degrade gracefully.

Comment: Does it work for IE 7-8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic is [history.pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries).

> ### Example
>
> Suppose http://mozilla.org/foo.html executes the following JavaScript:

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

> This will cause the URL bar to display http://mozilla.org/bar.html, but won't cause the >browser to load bar.html or even check that bar.html exists.

Comment: Here's a more descriptive [MDN page on the topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). Down at the bottom, someone inserted a reference to [Balupton's History.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js) in reference to cross-browser support. See the [litany of issues](https://github.com/balupton/history.js/wiki/The-State-of-the-HTML5-History-API), too.

Comment: @Jared: Does Hostory.js works for IE 7-8?

Comment: @Ricky - http://caniuse.com/#feat=history There's a reason there's nothing but `?` and `none` under IE on the `litany` link above.

Answer (score 1):

you can manipulate the browser history with javascript command like pushState/replaceState/popstate

Example:

```
function processAjaxData(response, urlPath){
     document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = response.html;
     document.title = response.pageTitle;
     window.history.pushState({"html":response.html,"pageTitle":response.pageTitle},"", urlPath);
 }
```